# sbt-assembly behaviour with jars and Spark

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager

I have doubt about the behaviour of sbt assembly:
When I use this configuration:

```
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "aopalliance", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "inject", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("org", "apache", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "google", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "codahale", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case PathList("com", "yammer", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.last
  case "about.html" => MergeStrategy.rename
  case "META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "META-INF/mailcap" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "META-INF/mimetypes.default" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "plugin.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "log4j.properties" => MergeStrategy.last
  case "git.properties" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

My output jar is about 109MB and it includes the spark library even though I set it as provided

but when I use this :

```
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case "src/test/resources/library.properties" => MergeStrategy.discard
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

My Jar is about 10MB. Do you know why?

Comment: JAR is just a ZIP with `class`es and resources. Show us the `ls -la` of content of both JARs unpacked and we'll be able to tell more.

Answer (score 0):

In the second strategy you are discarding all META-INF folders from your dependency jars (so these files are not copied on the far jar)

In any case you can unzip both jar files and check inside content to compare